# Tell git-blame to use imported history

Tags: git, svn, blame

I have a repository which was created by copying files (not the history) from an SVN repository, with many changes added on top since.

I have since converted the history in SVN into git, and merged it with `git merge -s ours`.

The problem is when I do a `git blame` on a file, it still shows every line as being created by the initial commit in the git repository (which copied all the files from SVN), rather than the SVN commit which was really responsible.

Is there a way I can solve this without rewriting all of the git history?

Comment: how many commits are there in the “git-only” history? Why do you not want to rewrite? Rewriting would probably be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [replacement ref](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-replace.html) for the initial commit from git to make it
appear to most git commands that the history which originated in git was built
upon history imported from svn.

With recent versions of git that can be done using the command:

```
git replace --graft <FIRST_GIT_COMMIT> <LATEST_SVN_COMMIT>
```

For older version which don't support that, you can do the same with the following commands:

```
git checkout -b temporary <FIRST_GIT_COMMIT>
# Set parent of next commit to last one from svn,
# but don't change the working tree or contents of next commit
git reset --soft <LATEST_SVN_COMMIT>
# Create a new commit using contents and message of the first git commit
git commit -C <FIRST_GIT_COMMIT>
# Tell git to use the newly created commit in place of the original git 
# commit in most cases.
git replace <FIRST_GIT_COMMIT> HEAD
```

But, in either case, replacement references do not get transferred automatically with the
standard refspecs used for remotes either when pushing or pulling.  Than can be
done manually by using:

```
git push origin 'refs/replace/*:refs/replace/*'
git pull origin 'refs/replace/*:refs/replace/*'
```

It is not possible to have the altered history automatically transferred to
other repositories without changing the commit ID of every commit which was
originally created with git.

Comment: A single command would probably also do the thing: `git replace --graft FIRST_GIT_COMMIT LATEST_SVN_COMMIT`

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev Yes, that was added since I'd originally written the answer. I've updated it to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: You may also need to run after `git filter-branch`